# Mongoengine with Django 1.8: ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value

Tags: python, django, mongoengine, django-database

I started a new Django project, using Django 1.8. I need MongoDB as a database, so I used mongoengine. The relevant section of my settings.py file is below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
}

from mongoengine import connect
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    from database_settings import TEST_DATABASE_PARAMS
    connect(
        TEST_DATABASE_PARAMS['db_name'], 
        username=TEST_DATABASE_PARAMS['username'], 
        password=TEST_DATABASE_PARAMS['password'],
        port=TEST_DATABASE_PARAMS['port']
    )
else:
    from database_settings import DATABASE_PARAMS
    connect(
        DATABASE_PARAMS['db_name'], 
        username=DATABASE_PARAMS['username'], 
        password=DATABASE_PARAMS['password'],
        port=DATABASE_PARAMS['port']
    )
```

The DATABASE_PARAMS and TEST_DATABASE_PARAMS dictionaries contain the correct database connection parameters - I checked. When I run

```
python manage.py test
```

however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 942, in setUpClass
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 907, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 907, in <genexpr>
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 60, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/features.py", line 216, in supports_transactions
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 164, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/p/projects/myproj/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 21, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

What's interesting is that this error doesn't occur when I start the Django shell, create a model object, and persist it into the MongoDB database. It works. The actual website also works fine. This happens only when running test.

Is this related to the latest version of Django, being version 1.8? I never had these problems in previous versions of Django. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Django raises this error while trying to process fixtures. For mongoengine you probably want to do it manually. So, one quick and dirty solution may be to override all methods that manage db connections

My solution (is probably not the most elegant one, but working):

**settings.py**

```
from mongoengine import register_connection

if 'test' in sys.argv:
    MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'dbname_test'
else:
    MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'dbname'

MONGO_DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': 99099,
    }
register_connection('default', MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, **MONGO_DATABASE_OPTIONS)
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings

class MongoTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        return

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        return

    def _fixture_setup(self):
        for fixture in self.fixtures:
            # process your data here
            pass

    def _post_teardown(self):
        db = _get_db()
        db.connection.drop_database(settings.MONGO_DATABASE_NAME)
```